# SPARK Yarn: Service or property not registered for Azure ServiceBus JAVA SDK

Tags: java, scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to get the SDK to work to send a simple message to the Azure Service Bus from a SPARK project. The code runs fine when i run it locally within a local spark context.

But when i submit this to YARN, at first i had a hard time trying to get the cluster to find the JAR files, now it executes with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Service or property not registered:  com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract interface com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract
```

My code for invoking the service bus is the following and i've tried it with and without the classloader part, still exactly the same issue:

```
  @throws[Exception]
  def SendMessageToSB(message: String) {


    try {

      // Get current context class loader
      val contextLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      // Change context classloader to class context loader
      contextLoader.loadClass("com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract")

      // Call Azure API and reset back the context loader

      val config: com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication("CTRATEST-NS$")
      val service: ServiceBusContract = ServiceBusService.create(config)
      val queueInfo: QueueInfo = new QueueInfo("inputdataqueue")
      try {
        val bm: BrokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message)
        service.sendQueueMessage("inputdataqueue", bm)
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => {
          System.out.print("ServiceException encountered: ")
          System.out.println(e.getMessage)
          System.exit(-1)
        }
      }


      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextLoader);
    }
  }
```

I've seen a similar thread with storm, but it points to the classloader problem which doesn't solve here since i'm using scala.

Azure SDK Version is 0.9.0 built via maven.

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, per my experience, I think you can try the code below.

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract


try {
    // Get current context class loader
    val contextLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    // Change context classloader to class context loader
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ServiceBusContract.class.getClassLoader))
    // Call Azure API and reset back the context loader

    val config: com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication("CTRATEST-NS$")
    val service: ServiceBusContract = ServiceBusService.create(config)
    val queueInfo: QueueInfo = new QueueInfo("inputdataqueue")
    try {
        val bm: BrokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message)
        service.sendQueueMessage("inputdataqueue", bm)
    } catch {
        case e: Exception => {
            System.out.print("ServiceException encountered: ")
            System.out.println(e.getMessage)
            System.exit(-1)
        }
    }
} catch {
    // handle exceptions  
} finally {
    // Reset back class loader
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextLoader)
}
```

If you want to load the class by name to JVM, you can try to use the code below.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract")
```

Comment: that was very helpful, thank you. By using the line  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ServiceBusContract.class.getClassLoader))  i was able to load the class and the issue went away.

Comment: That last line worked for me, thank you! Would be great to not have to use class loaders. but thats a story for another day.

Comment: Hi @PeterPan-MSFT  when am trying to modify the code with this line
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ServiceBusContract.class.getClassLoader))
am getting an error saying that expected identifier but class found near ServiceBusContract.class and I see "))" at the end of the line could you please let me know if am missing anything.
Thank You for Your help.